# How to Create Cart Price Rule Conditon in backend Configrations(system.xml)?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, system.xml

How to Create Cart Price Rule Conditon in backend Configrations system.xml
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't. Not without some kind of extension.

The query builder saves data to the database.

Comment: could you please check demo on this referer link https://store.webkul.com/magento2-order-approval.html